# Meaning of "that's fine" in modern American English when used as an answer to a question

Tags: american-english, north-american-english

I'm trying to understand (spoken) modern American English. Here's an example of my exchange:

> Me: Thank you for your payment. Would you like me to email you receipt?
>
> Respondent: All right. That's fine.

What do they mean by *That's fine*? Is it "yes" or "no"?

Comment: It means "I agree with that" or "I will accept that'.

Comment: I advise looking up the word *fine*.

Comment: Fine means very good, how could that possibly suggest "no"?

Comment: @Barmar: One person, "you've got to do it!" Another person, "I don't want to do it!" First person, "Fine!" meaning, "OK, don't do it."

Comment: That's "yes", since he's agreeing with what the second person said.

Comment: But it's also sarcastic, and in sarcasm words have opposite meanings. So he's agreeing, but not happy with it.

Comment: In your main example, if the respondent sighed before answering, he'd indicate that he'd prefer something else, but he'll take what he can get. But this would be weird in your context, where you're giving the respondent a choice.

Comment: @Barmar - Only if he's being sarcastic.  For instance, I'm NEVER sarcastic.

Comment: @Barmar - In Australia when a cashier in a shop asks if we want a receipt we sometimes say "No, that's fine" to mean "I don't want one, I'll be fine without it", and sometimes we shorten that response to just "that's fine" or "it's fine".

Comment: @nnnnnn The "No" before it is the important thing. In this case, "that's fine" means "what you've already done is fine"

Comment: @Barnard - Yes, I understand that. I was responding to your first comment above about how fine could mean no. I don't think there's confusion in context. In the OP's context the response was "All right. That's fine.", and I agree that that could only mean yes.

Comment: why would you think it doesn't mean yes?

Comment: In the exact exchange above, I would interpret it as meaning "I don't need a physical receipt; an emailed one is okay."

Answer (score 1):

Here in the States it is tricky due to the melting pot of cultures so "thats fine" could be interpreted as a simple acknowledgement/agreement to a passive aggressive way of showing ones upset/half-hearted agreement without actually saying the words. It all depends on the conversation. I would say in a professional setting, in general, it is used as an agreement/acknowledgement. Used in a personal setting its more looked at as rude... "can you watch my daughter for an hour, id appreciate it?" "Thats fine." This is a half-hearted or resistant agreement which comes off as "I really don't  want to but I will so I don't appear selfish or rude."

Answer (score 0):

The meaning of "That's fine" can be different in different cultures. Here in Australia, in the context you've described, it doesn't have to have a negative tone. I often hear it used as an iteration of "Alright". So, really meaning "Alright. Yes, please." or "Alright. Go ahead and send me the receipt."